# Insufficient permissions when trying to create a Quizlet set

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a set on Quizlet.com, using its API found here: https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/sets#add

Here is my code of a set I am trying to create:

```
import requests
quizkey = my_client_id
authcode = my_secret_code # I'm not sure if I need this or not
data = {"client_id":quizkey, "whitespace":1, "title":"my-api-set",
"lang_terms":"it", "lang_definitions":"en",
"terms":['uno','due'], "definitions":["one","two"]}
apiPrefix = "https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/sets"
r = requests.post(url=apiPrefix, params=data)
print r.text
```

The response is:

```
{
    "http_code": 401,
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_title": "Not Allowed",
    "error_description": "You do not have sufficient permissions to perform the requested action."
}
```

I also tried `"access_token":authcode` instead of `"client_id":quizkey`, but this resulted in the error: `"You do not have sufficient permissions to perform the requested action."`

How can I fix this and not get a 401 error?

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to send the request as a query string (that's what `params=` does) or are you supposed to embed it using `data=data`?

Comment: @JonClements I'm not sure. Whenever I use a GET request, I use `params=`, and it works just fine. I tried `data=data` and the same error occurs

Comment: Hi @TerryA, I'm facing the same issue as you, can you help by answer this question by yourself?

Comment: Hey @Blangero, I never got a working solution, let me see if I can try something now...

Comment: @Blangero I've added an answer, I hope it helps somewhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so 3 and a half years later (!!) I've looked into this again and here's what I've discovered.

To [add a set](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/sets#add) you need an access token - this is different to the client_id (what I call `quizkey` in my code), and to be quite honest I don't remember what `authcode` in my code is.

This token is obtained by going through the [user authentication flow](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization-code-flow). To summarise it:

- Send a POST request to `https://quizlet.com/authorize` like so:

  - `https://quizlet.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&scope=read&state=RANDOM_STRING`
  - Keep the response_type as `code`, replace `client_id` with your client_id, keep the scope as `read`, and state can be anything
  - I believe this requires human intervention because you're literally authorising your own account? Not sure of another way...
- You'll receive a response back with a code

  - Let's call this RESPONSE_CODE for now
- Send a POST request to `https://api.quizlet.com/oauth/token`, specifying 4 mandatory parameters:

  - `grant_type="authorization_code"` (this never changes)
  - `code=RESPONSE_CODE`
  - `redirect_uri=https://yourredirecturi.com` (this can be found [at your personal API dashboard](https://quizlet.com/api-dashboard))
  - client ID and secret token separated by a colon and then base64-encoded (the user authentication flow link above tells you what this is if you don't want to do any of the encoding)
- You'll receive the `access_token` from this API call

Now you can use that `access_token` in your call to create a set like I've done above (just replace `"client_id":quizkey` with `"access_token":access_token`)

Comment: Thank you so much @TerryA, what I want to know is just the human intervention part, so this means we can't write a program runs in the backend to create sets, right?

Comment: @Blangero I guess not since that's not what Quizlet's main intention was (Makes sense to prevent spam)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to authenticate in order to make sets. This link gives an overview:

https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/making_api_calls

And this one provides details about the authentication process:

https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization_code_flow